# On a Windows Form, how do I populate a data grid based on a many to many relationship?

Tags: winforms, data-binding, datagridview, datagrid, many-to-many

I have a C#, Windows Forms application.  One form is a maintenance page for all the accounts.  It was based on a single table in the table and a binding navigator was used to allow users to navigate through a list of accounts.  Each account had only one address.  Now I'm trying to change it so each account can have multiple addresses.  I've got a new table to store the addresses and a combo table to match the account to an address.  On the form, I added a data grid and added an addresses field (a list of addresses class) to the account class.  What I want to do is base the new data grid of the account's address field.  I can't figure out the exact syntax.  Can someone help me figure out how to bind the new data grid to the list of addresses?  Thank you!

So my code looks something like this (I've simplified the data to make it easier to include):

```
// This is how I originally bound my data source to the navigator on the form
List<Accounts> accounts = accountMaintenanceBLL.GetAccounts();
accountMaintenanceBindingSource.DataSource = accounts;

// Here's the original Account class; the addresses field is new to handle the multiple addresses
public class Account
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string account { get; set; }
    public List<Address> addresses { get; set; }
}

// Here's what the new address class looks like
public class Address
{
    public int AddressID { 
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to bind a new data grid to the addresses field in Account.  I've tried a few things, but basically I want to do something like this:

```
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = this.addressBindingSource;
addressBindingSource.DataSource = ((Address)itemMaintenanceViewModelBindingSource.Current).addresses;
```

This doesn't work and I can't quite figure out how to do it.

Here's a representation of the data:

```
Account Table
----------------------------
|  ID  |  Name  |  Account  |
-----------------------------
| 123  |  Acme  |  98765    |
-----------------------------
| 124  | Binford|  34566    |
-----------------------------
| 125  | CoTech |  32232    |
-----------------------------

Address Table
----------------------------------
|  Address  |  Address  |  City  |
|    ID     |           |        | 
---------------------------------|
|  1        | 123 Main  | Detroit|
----------------------------------
|  2        | 13 Elm    | Denver |
----------------------------------
|  3        | 90 Rodeo  | LA     |
----------------------------------
|  4        | 57 Park   | NYC    |
----------------------------------

AccountAddress Table
-----------------------------
|  Comp. ID  |  Address ID  |
-----------------------------
|  123       |  1           |
-----------------------------
|  124       |  2           |
-----------------------------
|  125       |  3           |
-----------------------------
|  125       |  4           |
-----------------------------
```

Here's a representation of the form with a binding navigator at the top, the account information as text boxes with the data, and then a grid showing the addresses for that account.

```
itemMaintenanceViewModelBindingNavigator

ID: 125     Name: Binford   Account: 34566
Addresses:

dataGridView1
------------------
| 90 Rodeo | LA  |
------------------
| 57 Park  | NYC |
------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

I am hoping this is correct. From what I can decipher, this appears to be similar to a “master-detail” type situation. It is a little confusing why the data shown appears to be `DataTable`s, however the code is using a `List<T>` as a `DataSource` to the grid?

Below uses a `List<Account>` as a `DataSource` to the `BindingSource`. As you have noted, that since the new “address” field is now a “collection” and not a single type... the grid is going to “ignore” this property. It is possible, to create a new “property” (not a method) that would return a “single” string with line breaks with all the different addresses and then display this in a “multiline” cell in the grid. Or using your suggestion that follows a master-detail idea is to create a second `DataGridView` to display the multiple addresses. This grids content will be “dynamic” and will change when the selection changes in the “accounts” grid.

Using the `Account` class as posted in the question and using a `BindingSource`, as in the posted code…

```
List<Accounts> accounts = accountMaintenanceBLL.GetAccounts();
accountMaintenanceBindingSource.DataSource = accounts;
```

Then we use this as a `DataSource` to the “Accounts” grid.

```
dgvAccounts.DataSource = accountMaintenanceBindingSource;
```

The next step is to setup the “Address” grids `DataSource`. Since this grids data source is “dynamic” and will change when the “Account” grids “selection” changes… this variable will need to be exposed to the “Account” grids “selection changed” event. This is the event used to “change” the “Address” grids data source. I am guessing there are other ways to achieve this and may need to be fine-tuned for your environment.

In this case a “global” `BindingSource` `AddressBindingSource` variable is used for the “Address” grids data source.

```
BindingSource AddressBindingSource = new BindingSource();
```

The forms load event may look something like below…

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  List<Account> accounts = GetAccounts();
  accountMaintenanceBindingSource.DataSource = accounts;
  dgvAccounts.DataSource = accountMaintenanceBindingSource;
  dgvAddresses.DataSource = AddressBindingSource;
}
```

Lastly is wiring up the “Accounts” grid `SelectionChanged` event to change the “Address” grids data source to the currently selected “Account”... it may look something like below…

```
private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  int rowIndex = dgvAccounts.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
  Account acct = (Account)dgvAccounts.Rows[rowIndex].DataBoundItem;
  AddressBindingSource.DataSource = acct.Addresses;
}
```

Above, we get the row index of the “current cells” row, then this row is mapped to the proper “Account” object in the `accounts` list. Lastly the “Address” binding source is set to that “Accounts” list of addresses.

I hope this helps.